# Separate values by ids in mongoose (distinct values)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my Node.js project I have *different subscription-packages (like package 1 is free, package 2 costs 10 bucks and so on)* for users to purchase. Now whenever new user purchases the package by existing user's link then existing user will get some benefits. And data generated is stored in the affiliation table.

Suppose, User A is existing user and he sends the link to the different people and people sign-ups and purchases the package.

**So the query is I want to show the user A that how many people purchased package no. 1 and how many people purchased package no. 2 and total amount of purchased package.**

I have tried the following code.

```
exports.getTotalReferral = async (user_id, start_date, end_date) => {
  let total_affiliation_amount = 0;
  let total_affiliation_record = 0;

  start_date = dayjs(start_date).utc(true).format();
  end_date = dayjs(end_date).endOf('day').utc(true).format();

  let data = await Affiliation.find(
    {
      affiliated_by: user_id,
      created_at: {
        $gte: start_date,
        $lte: end_date
      }
    },
  ).distinct('package_id', function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);  // this logs the result of the package id
  });

  return { data, total_affiliation_amount, total_affiliation_record };
}
```

See I have used the distinct on the find query but it throws the error `mongoose error: Query was already executed before` in the postman response but it **also logs** the package id data like this

```
[
  new ObjectId("63034e80ea402a28b0a91e44"),
  new ObjectId("63034e80ea402a28b0a91e45")
]
```

The controller where it is called:

```
exports.totalReferral = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const total_referral = await affiliationService.getTotalReferral(req.data.id, req.body.start_date, req.body.end_date);
    return res.succeed(total_referral, "success");

  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  };
};
```

How can I push the amount to the packageId and get rid of the error?

Comment: You don't need the callback function in the `distinct` method. The result is in the `data` variable - `let data = await Affiliation.find(...`. And, use the try-catch block for the `find` method to catch errors.

Comment: Ok that worked but how can I push the amount to that ids